# Working on a Lilypond part. The first few bars are missing from the pdf

Tags: pdf, lilypond

Trying to transpose the Goldenberg and Schmuyle part of Mussorski's pictures.
The first bars with rest disappear from the pdf if I include the second bar with the notes.
Same happens if I remove all grace-notes. Problems with 64'th notes?

Working example:

```
\header {
  title = "Pictures at an Exhibition"
  subtitle = "Samuel Goldenberg und Schmuyle"
  composer = "M. Mussorgskii"
  instrument = "Trumpet Eb"
  }
\version "2.18.2"

#(set-global-staff-size 16)
#(set-default-paper-size "a4")

<<
  \new Staff = ossia \with {
    \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
  }
  \new Staff \relative c' {
    \compressFullBarRests
    \clef treble \key es \major
    \time 4/4
    \tempo "Andante"

    \partial 32 r32 |
    r1 r r r \mark\markup\box{"5"} |
%   5
    r1 r |
    \time 3/4
    r2. |
    \time 4/4
    r1 \mark\markup\box{"9"} |
%   9
    \tempo 4 = 66
    \slashedGrace b''8 \tuplet 3/2 {b16\ff b b }    b64\(   c    b16.\)
    \slashedGrace b8   \tuplet 3/2 {b16 b b }       b64\(   c    b16.\)
    \slashedGrace ais8 \tuplet 3/2 {ais16 ais ais } ais64\( b    ais16.\)
    \slashedGrace gis8 \tuplet 3/2 {gis16 gis gis } gis64\( ais  gis16.\) |

%    \slashedGrace ais8 \tuplet 3/2 {ais16 ais ais } ais64\( b    ais16.\)
%    \slashedGrace dis,8 \tuplet 3/2 {dis16 dis dis } dis64\( e    dis16.\)
%    \slashedGrace dis8 \tuplet 3/2 {dis16 dis dis } dis64\( e    dis16.\)
%    \slashedGrace dis8 \tuplet 3/2 {dis16 dis dis } dis64\( e    dis16.\) |
}


>>

  \layout {
  \context {
    \RemoveEmptyStaffContext
    \override VerticalAxisGroup #'remove-first = ##t
    \override BarNumber #'padding = #3
    \override RehearsalMark #'padding = #2
    skipBars = ##t
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `\layout` block you have `\RemoveEmptyStaffContext` which removes a staff that has only rests.  I don't think you want that for a single horn part.